# Show that there exists a holomorphic function $f:C\backslash[0,1] \to{C}$ such that $\exp(f(z))=\frac{z-1}{z}$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}\backslash[0,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis

The hint for the problem says use the Schwartz reflection principle. Can I get some clues on how to proceed?

Comment: Umm... Can't you just rearrange to get $f(z)=\log\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$ ?

Comment: Then do I prove f(z) is holomorphic? How do I use the schwartz reflection to do that?@K.defaoite

Comment: I have not yet taken a complex analysis course so I will be of no use here, sorry. I was just making an observation.

Comment: @K.defaoite: A holomorphic logarithm does not exist on all of $\mathbb C$. The task here is essentially to prove that it does exist on a specific domain.

Comment: @curious-analyst: are your domains all correct? If $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$, then how can it be holomorphic, and how can $\exp(f)$ be defined on $\mathbb C\backslash[0,1]$?

Comment: Sorry @Vercassivelaunos.I have corrected the domain now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $z \to w = \frac{z-1}{z}$ maps the segment [0,1] to the closed half line $\{\infty\} \cup (-\infty,0] $, so the complement of [0,1] is mapped to the complex plane with a cut along the negative real numbers, and there is an analytic branch of logarithm defined in that domain.

Comment: Is it possible to get a more detailed proof? I dont see how the segment [0,1] maps to the closed half line ${\infty } \cup (-\infty,0]$? I believe it maps from $\infty$ to zero, the positive real axis. I need clarification on the first two statements. Once they are true, then  since we have an analytic branch of the logarithm, we have that it is holormorphic, correct? @VictorZurkowski

Comment: @curious_analyst $\frac {z-1} z= 1-\frac  1z$. Can you see what the image under $\frac  1z$ is ?

Comment: As I said, this maps to $(-\infty ,0]$. What about $\infty$ in Victor's answer.@KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1):

More detail here. Two ways, one geometry, the other analytic.

**Geometry argument**

Let $w = \frac{z-1}{z}$ (here $z \in \bar{\mathbb{C}}$; when $z=\infty$, the definition of $w$ should be understood to mean $w\Big|_{z=\infty}=1$). $w$ is a Mobious transformation of $z$. These transformations map lines or circles in $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$ to lines or circles. Being a continuous map, it maps connected sets to connected sets.

Note: In this context, when I said "lines" I mean, of course, a line in  $\mathbb{C}$, viewed as $\mathbb{R}^2$, union the point at infinity. Technically, the context is the projective line over $\mathbb{C}$.

So one can argue this way (draw 2 planes and arrows to follow):
The segment (of the real axis) [0,1] is contained on the real axis. We can pick 3 points on this line (I mean "line"!) and see where they are map. Take $z=0,1,\infty$, which are on the real line. They are mapped respectively to $w=\infty, 0,1$, and there is only one line/circle passing through these points: the real line.
If we remove $z=0,1,\infty$ from the real line, we end up with 3 connected segments, and by continuity they are map to connected pieces of the line removing $w=\infty, 0, 1$.

If $z$ is real and large (positive), on the connected piece of the real line from $1$ to $\infty$, then $w = \frac{z-1}{z}$ is *near $1-$*, so the connected piece $(1,+\infty)$ is mapped to the connected piece to the left of $1$, i.e. to $(0,1)$.

If $z$ is real and large negative, on the connected piece of the real line from $0$ to $\infty$, then $w = \frac{z-1}{z}$ is *near $1+$*, so the connected piece $(-\infty, 0)$ is mapped to the connected piece to the right of $1$, i.e. to $(1,+\infty)$.

Note: here $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are the same point. I am using $\pm$ to indicate the direction of approaching the point from the line, in a similar way to may use of $1-$ and $1+$, they are the same point, and the sign indicates a direction of approaching it from within the line.

Finally, the remaining connected piece, namely the segment $(0,1)$ must be mapped to the remaining piece, namely the half line $(-\infty,0)$.

Etc.

**Analytic argument**

If $w = \frac{z-1}{z}$, then $z = \frac{1}{1-w}$. For this approach we need to define the segment $[0,1]$ in terms of linear equations (i.e.: equations of the form $Re(\bar{\zeta}z) = c$, etc.) and *linear* inequalities.

The segment is defined as the simultaneous solution of:

1. $Im(z) = 0$
2. $0 \le Re(z)$
3. $Re(z) \le 1$

So, we write $z$ in terms of $w$, and simplify the expression to get the constraints on $w$.

Here follow the steps (here $z$ is generic, we handle the exceptions (when some denominator is 0, etc) by taking the closure at the end):

$Im(z)=0$
$Im( \frac{1}{1-w} ) = 0$
$Im( \frac{1 - \bar{w}}{|1-w|^2} )= 0$ iff $ \frac{Im(1 - \bar{w})}{|1-w|^2} = 0$, because $|1-w|^2$ is real
$ Im(w) = 0$ because $Im(1-\bar{w}) = 0 - Im(\bar{w}) = Im(w)$
This shows the line $Im(z)=0$ is mapped to the line $Im(w)=0$.

Now the inequalities. I'll do one only:
$Re(z) \le 1$
$Re( \frac{1}{1-w} ) \le 1$
$Re( \frac{1 - \bar{w}}{|1-w|^2} ) \le 1$
$Re( 1 - \bar{w}| ) \le |1-w|^2$ because  $Re( \frac{1 - \bar{w}}{|1-w|^2} ) = \frac{Re( 1 - \bar{w})}{|1-w|^2}$ and $|1-w|^2 > 0$, so passing it to the other side does not change the direction of the inequality
$1 - Re(w) \le 1 + |w|^2 - 2Re(w)$ because $Re(\bar{w})=Re(w)$, and for any $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, $|a-b|^2 = |a|^2 + |b|^2 - 2Re(\bar{a}b)$
$0 \le |w|^2 - Re(w)$
now we *complete the square*:
$0 \le |w|^2 - Re(w) = |w|^2 - 2Re(\frac{1}{2}w) + \frac{1}{2}^2 - \frac{1}{4} = |w - \frac{1}{2}|^2 - \frac{1}{4}$
$\frac{1}{2} \le |w - \frac{1}{2}|$
thus we get that the half plane $Re(z) \le 1$ is mapped to the exterior of the circle centered at $\frac{1}{2}$ of radious $\frac{1}{2}$

With similar steps one can get that $0 \le Re(z)$ is mapped to $Re(w) \le 1$.

Thus, the 3 equations defining the segment in terms of $z$, when expressed in terms of $w$ are:

1. $Im(w) = 0$
2. $\frac{1}{2} \le |w - \frac{1}{2}|  
   3) $Re(w) \le 1$

etc.

Note: the value of $w$ for $z=0, \infty$ is derived *by continuity*, and not by the formula of the Moebious transformation. Those points are analyzed either explicitly or implicitly (by continuity, taking the closure of the set we found).